# Distributed-element model of a series-RC transmission line

Tags: transmission-line, modeling

The equations for modelling most transmission lines can be based off the telegrapher's equations but the ones I found only account for parallel resistance with the capacitance, but I would like to model a resistance in series with the capacitance.

Image below of what I would like to model and below that is what most of the equations I found will model.

I'm not familiar enough with the underlying theory and math to make one from scratch, but if anyone knows where to find resources that apply to this I would be quite thankful.

[image: series RC transmission line]
[image: parallel RC transmission line]

Comment: Apply series to parallel RC conversion and then use the standard telegraphers equations.

Comment: Those conversions are only valid if the series resistance is tiny, and I should have mentioned I want to model the response down to DC.